# Conda 4.03 update MD5 sums mismatch

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Windows 10 Pro, x64, Anaconda 2.5.0, current conda 4.0.3

```
> conda update conda
```

failed for 4.0.3->4.0.4 update and now for 4.0.3->4.0.5 update with very similar message (modulo hash values):

> Error: MD5 sums mismatch for download: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/conda-4.0.5-py35_0.tar.bz2 (d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e != fcf55c185657b51475b17109104c03d1)

What went wrong?

When I d/l package manually (4.0.4 or 4.0.5), checksum matches with what is published by Continuum

Comment: If the MD5 sum doesn't match, then the package was either uploaded incorrectly or some bits are being flipped by your network connection while you download the file.

Comment: @cricket_007 Well, when I d/l package manually (4.0.4 or 4.0.5), checksum matches with what is published by Continuum

Comment: See: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2241. You can find a possible fix there as well.

Comment: @cel thank you, works for me. Care to write an answer so I could endorse it?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, please go ahead and self-answer your question with a fix that worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue for conda 4.0.3, see [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2232) for details. You have to downgrade first doing

```
> conda install conda=4.0.2
```

then

```
> conda update conda
```

will work again and push you to 4.0.5 without problems